# Проектирование БД для многоязычного проекта

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Мой мозг, размягченный NoSQL, совсем отказывается проектировать нормальную реляционную БД.

Задача такова:

- Есть сущности: карточки, теги, категории. Возможно, позже появится что-то еще;
- У каждой сущности есть связи, которые не зависят от языка;
- У каждой сущности есть текстовые поля, которые надо переводить (количество языков не велико, в начале проекта будет 2, позже добавится еще 2-3).

Нужно спроектировать базу так, что бы минимизировать время работы запросов на получение отдельной карточки и списка карточек с переводом текстовых полей на нужный язык.

Стек технологий проекта: PostgreSQL, SQLAlchemy, Flask

**UPDATE**

gettext не подойдет, так как требуется перевод для описаний и т.п. с возможностью редактирования в админке.

Comment: а зачем через базу переводить? [gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) не подойдет? тем более, что для python'a он из [коробки идет](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html)

Comment: А насколько много локаллизаций? Почему бы всё при старте не затянуть и бог  бы с ним как оно там храниться, а если каждый раз вытягивать локализации без кэширования, то как бы не хранилось не поможет ничего...

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov, gettext активно использует кэширование. Иногда, правда, косячки всплывают, когда после изменения исходного файла, gettext все равно отдает старую версию строки, но это легко лечится. Использование проверенного решения все-таки лучше, чем самописное на коленке

Comment: @BOPOH это да, но я бы в файликах локализацию не хранил... тем более когда БД доступна.

Comment: @ВОРОН А в gettext не будет проблем с добавлением новых слов на лету ?

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov Проблема в том, что для реляционной БД, если все делать _правильно_ есть только 1 путь `create table (id-строки, id-языка, текст)`. Но вы же хотите, что бы это быстро работало ... Думаю надо посмотреть особенности выбранной СУБД вдруг какое-нибудь решение из не стандартизированных у нее есть

Comment: VladislavPyatkov, а БД - это разве не файлы? @Mike, смотря какие проблемы интересуют, та же django [использует gettext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/), так что, думаю, все решаемо

Comment: @BOPOH нет, это понятие более высокого уровня. Это позволяет партицировать, масштабировать, делать инкрементальные бэкапы, выносить на отдельные вычислительне мощности и прочее.

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov, gettext это тоже не просто файлики. Данные что здесь, что в базе хранятся в файлах, но их работа не только к чтению сводится. gettext - распространенный и проверенный инструмент, так почему не использовать его? Если задействовать всю мощь БД только ради такой задачки - то мы из пушки по воробьям стрелять будем. Я не говорю, что вместо БД однозначно gettext, а иначе расстрел. Но если инструмент прекрасно справляется с задачей, для которой он был создан, то зачем от него отказываться? Это только вариант, решать все равно автору

Comment: Посмотрел в postrgess есть массивы, но хз что там по производительности и насколько удобно будет работать. Ораклового create cluster (совместное хранение связанных таблиц в одних блоках данных), которое было бы хорошим решением этой задачи в постгресе я не нашел

Comment: @BOPOH да нет, я имею введу что для десктопного приложения вот такие штуки отличное решение, быстро развернулось без всяких там сервисов и работает в одной локале пока его не удалят. А для веб сервиса, там и локаллизаций гора если сервис долго жить будет и требования постоянно меняются, орфографию правят, да и контент едит из-за фраз не по размеру...

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov, не вижу проблемы в постоянном редактировании контента. Вы же его редактируете, значит при сохранении локализацию может будет изменить. django - это не декстоп, поэтому я на него и сослался. Еще - [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/gettext) вроде использует его для своих сайтов, [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) и [Drupal](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/4cc037d4dd9b52ee59eecb3bbf1795c75c0ead5a/modules/locale/locale.module) предоставляют локализацию через gettext и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набор языков фиксированный? Если да, добавляйте локализованные поля к полям, которым нужен перевод, постфиксы *_ru, *_en и т.д.

Если нет - создайте что нибудь типа translation: id, key, value - и используйте ссылки на них, вместо прямых значений полей.

Answer (score 1):

Есть множество решений, могу предложить одно, которое можно легко присоединять в одном запросе как пример в MySQL (JOIN)

Есть таблица как основная с карточками, у неё структура примерно такая:

```
cards - ID | COLOR | VIEWS | CREATED
```

И есть вспомогательная таблица с переводами

```
card_languages - ID | CARD_ID | LANGUAGE | NAME | DESCRIPTION
```

ну и как пример в MySQL:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name, b.description FROM cards a LEFT JOIN card_languages b ON b.card_id=a.id WHERE b.langauge=1
```

Comment: Боюсь это единственное решение, но по производительности, тем более с left join оно мягко говоря не идеально

Comment: @Mike, согласен. Похоже это действительно единственное решение. Сверху придется видимо вьюху сделать. Что бы все-таки чтение без left join работало

Comment: ну вьюха от лефт джоина не спасет, по факту он все равно выполнятся будет. И кстати, а каково поведение если запрошен английский, а карточка только на русском есть. совсем пустые поля выводить как-то не хорошо....

Comment: @Mike что критично плохого в left join? Если настолько боитесь пересечений, создавайте обновляемые таблицы-вьюхи для каждого языка.

Comment: @Etki Встроенным в СУБД оптимизаторам запросов left крышу часто сносят. Ну и плюс надо реализовывать дефолтное поведение, т.е. если строка на языке есть - брать ее, если нет - то возможно брать для дефолтного языка, а это на производительности точно хорошо не скажется

Comment: @Mike *Встроенным в СУБД оптимизаторам запросов left крышу часто сносят* - точно? - *то возможно брать для дефолтного языка, а это на производительности точно хорошо не скажется* - еще одно условие после LEFT JOIN точно хорошо не скажется? По-моему, вы просто избегаете вещей, существование которых толком не доказано.

Comment: @Mike CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW вроде как спасает от left join. На счет дефолтного поведения: нет перевода = нет карточки для конкретного языка.

Comment: @AlexKorablev, вы не желаете использовать join ссылаясь на производительность, но при этом, соглашаясь на join, желаете спрятать его во view? Со view вы же напрочь убиваете возможность задействования иных составных индексов на таблицах, которые могут ускорить некоторые выборки, оставляя лишь то, что может задействовать сам view.

Answer (score 0):

В нашем проекте, рассмотрев несколько вариантов, остановились на том, чтобы хранить многоязычные данные в виде XML.

В нашем случае речь шла о MS SQL, но Postgres, [как я вижу](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support), тоже понимает XML-поля.

Из явных минусов — невозможность индексирования по таким полям, и отсутствие поддержки оператора `LIKE 'prefix%'`. Полнотекстовый поиск всё же возможен (хотя объём такового для PostgreSQL оценить не берусь).

Ещё один минус — необходимость поддерживать такие поля с помощью уровня предметной области (то есть такие поля труднее читать и править вручную).

Answer (score 0):

Подсмотрел подходящее решение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323365).

Для каждой карточки сделать отдельную таблицу с переводом:

```sql
CREATE TABLE T_PRODUCT (pr_id int, PRICE NUMBER(18, 2))

CREATE TABLE T_PRODUCT_tr (pr_id INT FK, languagecode varchar, pr_name text, pr_descr text)
```

Карточка собирается одним простым джоином. FallBack по языкам сделать правда сложнее, но для задачи и не требовалось.